# Не получается создать список списков из списка

Tags: python, list, списки

Есть список

```
a = [9, 1, 9, 74888, 29, 2, 29, 55586, 29, 2, 29, 19827, 
     23, 2, 23, 62839, 50, 3, 50, 56642]
```

Необходимо чтобы каждые 4 элемента были объединены во вложенный список вот так:

```
a = [[9, 1, 9, 74888], 
     [29, 2, 29, 55586], 
     [29, 2, 29, 19827], 
     [23, 2, 23, 62839], 
     [50, 3, 50, 56642]]
```

Никак не получается это сделать циклом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [24]: N=4

In [25]: res = [a[i*N : i*N+N] for i in range(len(a) // N + (len(a) % N > 0))]

In [26]: res
Out[26]:
[[9, 1, 9, 74888],
 [29, 2, 29, 55586],
 [29, 2, 29, 19827],
 [23, 2, 23, 62839],
 [50, 3, 50, 56642]]
```

проверка для списка, длина которого не кратна `N`:

```
In [54]: a = [9, 1, 9, 74888, 29, 2, 29]

In [55]: res = [a[i*N : i*N+N] for i in range(len(a) // N + (len(a) % N > 0))]

In [56]: res
Out[56]: [[9, 1, 9, 74888], [29, 2, 29]]
```

Comment: спасибо, работает